# How to declare an array to contain a list of dates in vb

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, date

I am trying to initialize an array to contain a list of dates that i can loop through

01/01/2016

06/03/2016

25/03/2016

28/03/2016

01/05/2016

25/05/2016

or is there a way i can store these dates without using arrays or strings?
please any suggestion/help is greatly welcomed. thnx

Answer (score 0):

sorry you cannot save date to array.

but here is the link that might help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/8k8021te(v=vs.90).aspx